# How to make C++ portable app with DataBase (SQlite)

Tags: c++, sqlite

So, I have a simple console app and I want to use DataBase in it. I want that program to be portable(I mean if I bring that program to another pc without that db engine it should work)

For example i want to work with SQLite. Will it be enough if i will add `sqlite3.h` in header of my program? Or I need to do something else

And one more question. What is wrappers for Sqlite ?

Comment: You should probably link statically with the SQLite3 library as well.

Comment: Link to sqlite3.h and  sqlite3.c http://sqlite.org/sqlite-amalgamation-3071300.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be fine including sqlite3.h and compiling sqlite3.c with your project.

Answer (score 0):

It will also require you to have a library (.so / .dll) near the binary, or you should link your application with the static library of engine.

Wrappers are some kind of functions and/or classes that makes it easier to use the main library.